# Database installation in Kubernete using helm chart got an error no matches for kind "PodDisruptionBudget" in version "policy/v1beta1"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, failed-installation, milvus

Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "PodDisruptionBudget" in version "policy/v1beta1"

minikube version : v1.28.0
helm version: v3.5.4+g1b5edb6
OS: Ubuntu

I am trying to install milvus cluster database in kubernete using helm chart.

Comment: It looks like more recent versions of Kubernetes use API version `policy/v1`. You would need to update the manifests to use the new version.

Comment: I am already using updated manifests @larsks

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. You would need to update the manifests *in the helm chart* so that they use the appropriate API version. The easiest way to do that may be to identify the problematic manifest and then submit a pull request against the milvus-helm repository.

Comment: Can you specify the helm charts? I checked these ones https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus-helm/tree/master/charts/milvus/templates - seems like PodDistributionBudget is nto defined here

Comment: while using the kubernete version v1.25.0, this problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Search for the file ***poddisruptionbudget.yml*** who should likely be located in folder ../cp-zookeeper/templates

change

```
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1 
to 
apiVersion: policy/v1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you need to update your helm repo, to get a version of the helm chart that has been updated to work with the latest kubernetes.  E.g. if you are dealing with elasticsearch, you might do `helm repo update elastic`.